# Splitting Voting and Baking rights

Tags: baking, voting

What's the design barrier, that prevents us from splitting of Voting and Baking rights?

Is it not desired? Or is it not possible?

Answer (score 5):

It is desired and absolutely possible.

We are actively working on it. I think we should be ready to share the specification with the community in 3-4 weeks and then a prototype the month after.

Comment: Could you specify the "we" here? :)

Answer (score 5):

It was also mentioned by Jacob Arluck in this [Medium article](https://medium.com/tezos/amending-tezos-b77949d97e1e).

> In this post, I describe how the Tezos amendment process works in
>   practice and propose several ways to improve it in the near-term.
>   Deeper questions, like splitting voting rights from consensus, or how
>   amendments should be funded on-chain are outside the scope of this
>   post, but important topics for future consideration.